# Performance Advantages / Disadvantages of using Views in Mongo DB

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data, aggregation-framework

I have a really complex aggregation query, so I thought to use view as below:

```
 db.createView("weNeed","Master",
 [
{$project:
     {
         _id:"$_id",
         documents:{
            $concatArrays:[
             {$ifNull:
             [{$map:{
                input:"$documents.COMPLETED",
                 as:"document",
                 in:{
                     entity:"$name",
                     status:"COMPLETED",
                     name:"$$document.name",
                     category:"$$document.category",
                     description:"$$document.description",
                     submittedDate:"$$document.submittedDate",
                     expirationDate:"$$document.expirationDate",
                     uri:"$$document.uri"

                     }
             }},[]]},
             {$ifNull:
             [{$map:{
                input:"$documents.REQUIRED",
                 as:"document",
                 in:{ entity:"$name",
                     status:"REQUIRED",
                     name:"$$document.name",
                     category:"$$document.category",
                     description:"$$document.description",
                     submittedDate:"$$document.submittedDate",
                     expirationDate:"$$document.expirationDate",
                     uri:"$$document.uri"
                     }
             }},[]]},
             {$ifNull:
             [{$map:{
                input:"$documents.DEFERRED",
                 as:"document",
                 in:{ entity:"$name",
                     status:"DEFERRED",
                     name:"$$document.name",
                     category:"$$document.category",
                     description:"$$document.description",
                     submittedDate:"$$document.submittedDate",
                     expirationDate:"$$document.expirationDate",
                     "uri":"$$document.uri"
                     }
             }},[]]}
             ]
         }
     }
     }
     ]
     )
```

Now, I could easily use aggregation on it. Also, In `java-springdata` I could easily create a matching Repository and access the data easily.Same applies to any other language or framework. This also gives a good view of what I need.

See Below query which is very concise in size:-

```
db.weNeed.aggregate([
{
    $project:{
        documents:"$documents"
        }
    },
    {$unwind:"$documents"},
    {$sort:{
        "documents.entity":1,
        "documents.category":1,
        "documents.status":1,
        "documents.name":1
        }}
]
)
```

I tried to find if there are any performance fall backs of using views over single aggregation query. Haven't got any.

Below are some advantages of view as per me:-

1. Cleaner code.
2. A view of your data, hence could be viewed from database without running complex query.
3. Gets updated as soon as there is any save or update in original Collection.
4. Better performance as not single collection is queried.

Disadvantages:- This i am not sure much about. Still I think
1. Could not be good with Clustreing.
2. Could be good for people who have less knowledge of mongo and want to use any wrapper framework.

Also, there is no official documentation mentioning any advantages and disadvantages.

Please help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In terms of performance, I believe you don't get any benefit as view does not store any data. It only stores the query in `system.views`. So every time you are going to access the views it will actually execute the aggregation query if you do not have a proper index on your collection then you can expect a slow response. As views don't store any data, so it `can't be indexed`.

Take a look at [this](https://dzone.com/articles/taking-a-look-at-mongodb-views) for some information.

Comment: Can you please share any supporting documentation for same?

Comment: Sure. Take a look on the article. https://dzone.com/articles/taking-a-look-at-mongodb-views

Comment: I would like to hold for some time before accepting it.Want to see more good information coming in for same. Thanks @amit

Comment: Views can be stored on disk now. Per Mongo Documentation: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/views/


MongoDB provides two different view types: standard views and on-demand materialized views. Both view types return the results from an aggregation pipeline.

Standard views are computed when you read the view, and are not stored to disk.

On-demand materialized views are stored on and read from disk. They use a $merge or $out stage to update the saved data.

Answer (score 9):

I am finding views quite useless for work with any larger collection, and unfortunately that is where I live. Looks to me that the view `find()` execution does not have an intelligence to integrate `find()` filter object into the view, but rather runs the view by scanning the whole collection, and then attempts to filter the resulting list, resulting in slow performance.

**Example:**

```
db.createView(myView,myCol,[{stage1}..{stageN}]);
db.myView.find({myFilter});
```

...is MUCH slower on large myCol than:

```
db.myCol.aggregate([{"$match":{myFilter}},{stage1}..{stageN}])
```

(provided that `{"$match":{myFilter}`} is a valid aggregation stage)

Dynamically integrating filter into views aggregation would actually make the view concept workable.

Comment: I don't know how it was then, but by now this answer is definitely no longer correct. MongoDB will move all filters applied to a view that are not dependent on its pipeline to the beginning of the pipeline, so no collection scan is performed at all. The operation has pretty much the same performance as if you would do it yourself.
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#pipeline-sequence-optimization